# SASS without Ruby for .NET application

Tags: css, .net, ruby, sass, less

I've been recently reading up on SASS(Simply Awesome StyleSheets) on codeschool but when I actually tried installing it, it turns out I need to install RVM(Ruby) as SASS was written in Ruby.

So I have a two questions here:

1. I understand that there are other CSS frameworks like LESS but they don't seem to be as powerful/popular. How true is this? I wouldn't mind switching to LESS if does not need Ruby at all.
2. Is there a compiler for SASS in .NET or Java family of languages and if there is, how production ready is it? I do not want to keep checking the generated CSS file when debugging or making changes.

Comment: LESS is currently equally powerful as SASS, and its compiler runs on Node.js. There is however, a .NET based compiler: http://dotlesscss.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This really comes down to what you want to your preprocessor to do and which fits your project requirements the best.  People will argue either or all day long.  For me what I see the main difference is that in LESS I can't do as many programatical things, like loops, for each statements.  That kind of thing.
2. SASS is ruby based, therefore you need to have ruby installed.  There are extensions you can use in Visual Studio to make SASS compiling easier. [Web workbench](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench) and [Sassy Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/85fa99a6-e4c6-4a1c-9f00-e6a8129b6f4d).  Support will be coming to Web Essentials some time soon.

So I think it comes down to which you think fits best.  I prefer to use LESS in Visual Studio (using DotLess) just because I feel it's better supported and I don't need to install Ruby (I big consideration when working with multiple developers).

Comment: Considering extensions in VS, how accurate is the compiled CSS?

Comment: How accurate? It compiles it correctly if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

> 1.I understand that there are other CSS frameworks like LESS but they don't seem to be as powerful/popular. How true is this? I wouldn't
>   mind switching to LESS if does not need Ruby

Here is my take on this.

LESS like SASS is a CSS preprocessor but it is pure JS based and thus can be parsed directly by browser if you include less.js file in head. You may also generate a CSS file offline and then ship it to production. Please note that you will need node.js to actually run LESS. LESS is built on top of it. LESS if not more powerful than SASS, is equally powerful in terms of features. Go ahead and use LESS, you'll never miss a thing about SASS.

> 2.Is there a compiler for SASS in .NET or Java family of languages and if there is, how production ready is it? I do not want to keep
>   checking the generated CSS file when debugging or making changes.

There is actually a C version of SASS called `libsass`. See its site at http://libsass.org/.Libsass is just a library. To run the code locally (i.e. to compile your stylesheets),you may use SassC https://github.com/hcatlin/sassc , an implementer written in C.